# h264 encode video stream ffmpeg c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to develop A live streaming app that capture video from web cam encode it to **H264** video stream and use rtsp to send it to device,
I've looked up some examples and found this:
[FFMPEG to send RTSP encoded stream C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877380/ffmpeg-to-send-rtsp-encoded-stream-c)

I've been using it as a reference to my program.

However I'm keep getting AVCodec type "MPEG", I've been trying to change *filename* extension and tried different approaches with *avformat_alloc_output_context2*

This is the relevant code:

```
const char *filename = "rtsp://127.0.0.1:7003/live.sdp";
AVOutputFormat *fmt;
AVFormatContext *oc;
AVStream *video_st;
AVCodec *video_codec;
video_st = NULL;

av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
// format context:
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc,NULL,"rtsp",filename);
```

After calling *avformat_alloc_output_context2* oc->oformat->video_codec is generated as MPEG codec.
I've tried changing filename extension to:

```
const char *filename = "rtsp://127.0.0.1:7003/live.264";
const char *filename = "rtsp://127.0.0.1:7003/live.h264";
```

and a bunch of other extensions.

How can I generate a H264 stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avformat_8h.html), you need to pass an output format to `avformat_alloc_output_context2`.

To quote (content in square brackets mine):

> [the second parameter is the] format to use for allocating the context, if NULL format_name and filename are used instead

This parameter is a pointer to type [AVOutputFormat](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVOutputFormat.html).

Alternatively, you could continue to pass `NULL` and infer the output by using H264 as the format name.

Either way, I think you'll need to separate the encoding process from the streaming protocol.

This separation of concerns is useful, as if you find you want to use a different protocol to get the stream, the encoding code does not need to know about it.

Comment: AVOutputFormat is generated inside (AVFormatContext) oc when calling avformat_alloc_output_context2, that's why when passing NULL as the second argument the method should "guess" what's the appropriate format.

Comment: @Hahn try manually setting it, just to be sure. Also, you should try another codec to see if the problem is isolated to RTSP (try H264 directly?)

Comment: Thanks OMGtrchy, setting h264 instead rtsp worked, however will I still want to stream the video with rtsp protocol, will that work?

Comment: @Hahn just updated the answer. If you're still having trouble, I'll write up something more extensive when I have more time (on my phone currently).