# RTSP Server using ffmpeg code has wrong ffmpeg version?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm trying to reuse the sample code of next topic, but it does not run with ffmpeg-20190320.

Topic: [FFMPEG to send RTSP encoded stream C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877380/ffmpeg-to-send-rtsp-encoded-stream-c)

I tried to change the include line to the right paths, but some files are simple gone.

All of the code can be found on the topic referring to.

I'm expecting the code from the referring topic to build and run as expected with the newer version of ffmpeg or to know what version was used so I can try to refactor it myself.

Comment: `but some files are simple gone.` What files? Why are they gone? What happens when you restore/replace/install them?

Comment: @szatmary I was referring to the avfiltergraph header file in libavfilter which is removed in newer versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the code building and running with 
ffmpeg-2.0.1-win32-shared and 
ffmpeg-2.0.1-win32-dev found on 
https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/dev/ and https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/, but I had to use the wayback machine.